# How to trigger a letter in a cell when something is put in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Example: when I enter 24 in A1, I would like the letter "x" to appear in B1.  I hope this makes sense.  I don't know a lot about macros or would a simple formula work?

Comment: The range of conditions you want to cover isn't clear. Is 24 (or some other single value), the only value you want to check for? Are there multiple targets with different letters assigned? Are you trying to map numbers to letters of the alphabet, as Paul suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, with the IF statement. In B1 put

```
=IF(A1=24,"x","")
```

Or, if you want code mapping, so that it works for all numbers to letters, you can do:

```
=CHAR(A1+96)
```

This works because the letter 'x' is at position 96+24 in the ASCII character set (this working is depending on the character set you use, but will generally work).

If you want upper case 'X' then change this to

```
 =CHAR(A1+64)
```

If you want any number to cause x to appear:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(A1),"x","")
```

Comment: Let say there is nothing in A1.  When I put (any number) in A1 the letter x will appear in B1 as soon as any number is put into A1.

Comment: @jay Updated answer.